# re.compile() python: issue in getting particular pattern

Tags: python

I have been trying to extract particular pattern, which looks like `(PSSA)` or `(FJFD10)` in a string.

In a string like this, I want to extract for instance something inside that parentheses `(PNDM)` in this case. However, I wanted to print it without parentheses.

```
eg_string = """DAAAAAAJFF: Hellllllllo (PNDM)
CC       [MIM:606176]: Blalblablalbalbl. {CCO:0000069|Pubd:160,
CC       ECO:0000269|PubMed:18162506}. Note=elllelefjfjfjf HAahndfd
"""
```

What I did was:

```
patti = re.compile(r'([A-Z]+)')
www = patti.findall(eg_string)
```

However, this was giving me more than I needed. It did include `PNDM`, but it also included like `DAAAJFF`, `ECO`

Another thing I tried was `r'(^[A-Z]+)` I knew it was going to print out `DAAAAAJFF` only. I want to know how to print `(PNDM)` which is in the middle of the string.

Comment: I am not sure how to specify it to the value inside the parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `([A-Z]+)` is consider as pattern like A-Z any number of times but you need to change it as `\(([A-Z]+)\)`
Your Code will be like

```
import re
eg_string = """DAAAAAAJFF: Hellllllllo (PNDM)
CC       [MIM:606176]: Blalblablalbalbl. {CCO:0000069|Pubd:160,
CC       ECO:0000269|PubMed:18162506}. Note=elllelefjfjfjf HAahndfd
"""
patti = re.compile(r'\(([A-Z]+)\)')
www = patti.findall(eg_string)
print(www)

#Output : ['PNDM']
```

Hope this will Help...

Answer (score 1):

Use the regex: `r"\([A-Z]+\)"` to get text results for including `()`.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/e2gyly/1

Explanation:

```
\( - will look for opening brace (
[A-Z] - any char between range A to Z 
\) - closing brace )
```